# Angular how to compile whole jTable after dynamic load from server

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am using .NET to assemble some of the fields on the server for jTable. My problem is how to compile changed table after load, so angular events are compiled to `$scope`. What I've tried is to compile the whole html body, but it doesn't work. Nothing happens. What should I do? Some fields must be assembled on the server. Why is `$compile($("body"))($scope)` not compiling whole body?

My thinking is that whatever element is added to DOM, if I compile the whole documents body, all angular events should be binded to `$scope`.

Here is the function on the server (`ng-blur` event is added to the input field `inputQuantity`):

```
public JsonResult GetListFromIACC_KEY(int jtStartIndex, int jtPageSize, string orderBy)
{
  List<DTO_CAMERC> listResults = new List<DTO_CAMERC>();
      x.Quantity = SetTextBoxFieldInJTable(value: x.Quantity, 
      attribute1: @"id='inputQuantity'", 
      attribute2: @"ng-blur='alert();'");
      return x;
    }).OrderBy(x => x.iMERC_KEY).ToList();
  }
  return Json(new { Result = "OK", Records = listResults, TotalRecordCount = listResults.Count });
}
```

Function for creating input field:

```
private string SetTextBoxFieldInJTable(string value = null, string attribute1 = null, string attribute2 = null)
{
  return @"<input type='text' class='cellContent'" +  
  "value='" + value + @"' " + attribute1 + " " + 
  attribute2 + ">";
}
```

Client call (here I've tried to compile whole html body after jTable has loaded, but id doesn't work - nothing happens when field inputQuantity loses focus):

```
$http({
  method: "POST",
  url: $scope.UrlSetIACCO_KEY,
  data: JSON.stringify(model)
}).then(function success(response) {

  jQuery('#tblDeliveryList').jtable('load');

  //Here I try to compile the whole body, after the jTable has loaded,
  //but ng-blur is not working
  $compile($("body"))($scope);

}, function failure() {
  alert("Napaka!");
})
});
```

Table on the client:

```
jQuery('#tblDeliveryList').jtable({
  title: 'Delivery',
  paging: true,
  pageSize: 10,
  sorting: true,
  defaultSorting: 'cMERC_NME ASC',
  actions: {
    listAction: $scope.UrlGetDataFromIACCO_KEY
  },      
    Quantity: {
      title: 'Quantity',
      width: '3%',
      sorting: false
    }
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing the compile wrong. `$('body')` returns a jQuery object. What you need to do is to return HTML dom object for angular to compile. Also, compiling the jTable html alone is enough. Try the following:

```
$compile(document.getElementById('tblDeliveryList'))($scope);
```

Comment: There was another trick: I had to wait, until page is rendered. I've figured it out, that page is not rendered when recordsLoaded event is fired, but a few miliseconds after -> that is why I've used one asnyc method to wait a couple of miliseconds and then call $compile. Thanks for your answer.